# Is it possibile to create a static Struct with these HashMap? And is Mutex needed in this case?

Tags: rust

I need a `Store` struct like this:

```rust
pub struct Store {
  pub players: HashMap<(String, i64), Player>,
  pub teams: HashMap<(String, i64), Team>,
}

impl Store {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
      players: HashMap::new(),
      team: HashMap::new(),
    }
  }
}
```

The values in those `HashMap` are used as "shared, request-scoped memory" and then deleted (using `.remove(k)`).

#### QUESTIONs

1. Since I don't care if two or more requests write/read the same entries at the same time (very unlikely) should I still use `Mutex`?

   ```rust
   // Like this?
   let store = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Store::new()))

   // Or this?
   pub fn new() -> Self {
     Self {
       players: Mutex::new(HashMap::new()),
       team: Mutex::new(HashMap::new()),
     }
   }
   ```
2. Since the store is created when the application starts and is never destroyed, would it be useful to create a `'static` one thus avoiding the use of `Arc` too?

   ```rust
   // Something like:
   const store: &mut Store = &mut Store::new();
   ```

**UPDATE**:

I'm trying to use this store to avoid nested structs issues like:

```rust
struct Player {
  id: String,
  team: Box<Team>, // see the Box here
}
```

So I'm trying to use flat, plain data like:

```rust
struct Player {
  id: String,
  team_id: String,
}
```

but I need something to use as store.

Comment: `const`s are different from `static` vars. `const`s act more like `#define`s. You can't mutate a `const`, and the compiler will require you to wrap the `static` in a `Mutex` anyways. Can you expand more on what "shared, request-scoped memory" means? What makes it shared, and why does it have to be? What library are you using to serve requests (many have a request storage already)?

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ. I updated the question to better explain my needs.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer either of my questions. It also doesn't even explain why `Team` can't just go directly inside the `Player`, unboxed. Do `Team`s refer to `Player`s, and `Player`s also refer back to `Team`s?

Comment: Yep. They refer each other. But this is a graphql endpoint backend...

Comment: I would like to avoid the mess with `Box`.

Comment: It's unclear how `Box` would even solve that problem in the first place. Please provide more details. You still haven't answered my original questions. What libraries are you using? Why does the `Store` need to be shared? Why can't you just create a new one on each request?